# DAO.Recordset returns table name instead of column value

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-10

Original post [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/access-2016-daorecordset-returns-table-name/036034cd-6cef-476b-ac1a-81bf93ba77d2).

Just wondering if anyone here has had any recent DAO VBA issues in Access 2016/2019 where the same code works just fine in 2007. This issue seems to have sprouted around June 10th, but I can't seem to find any Windows 10/Office 2016/2019 Click-To-Run updates correlating specifically with DAO references.

**EDIT**

Here's the original code where it's pulling the table name through in Access 2016/2019 in lieu of the column value in Access 2007. This code use to pull the column value in 2016/2019 as well, but it hasn't since ~June 10th, 2020:

```
'Declare stuff
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Dim sReportType As String, sYear As String, SGroup As String, sGroupID As String, sGroupRptId2 As String
Dim sGLCode As String, sGLCodeStart As String, sGLCodeEnd As String
Dim sPeriod As String, sPeriodStart As String, sPeriodEnd As String
Dim sListInactiveAccts As String
Dim sRptTitleA As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Set DB = CurrentDb()
Dim Q As QueryDef
Set Q = DB.QueryDefs("G/L Trial Balance")
Dim localRS As DAO.Recordset, localRS2 As DAO.Recordset


'Determine year to use based on YearSelection drop-down

If Me.YearSelection = "Current year" Then 'If "Current Year" is selected, get the year of the current fiscal
    sSQL = "SELECT a FROM table WHERE (((table.b)=""A""));"
    Set localRS = DB.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)        

    sYear = localRS(0).Value        

    localRS.Close
ElseIf Me.YearSelection = "Prior year" Then 'If "Prior Year" is selected, ensure a year is entered in the "Prior Year:" text box
    If IsNull(Me.PriorYearInput) Then 'If there isn't one, go to text box and notify end user
        DoCmd.GoToControl "PriorYearInput"
        MsgBox "Please enter a year in the ""Prior Year:"" field."
        Exit Sub
    Else 'If there is one, use it!
        sYear = Me.PriorYearInput
    End If
End If    

MsgBox Me.YearSelection & ", " & sYear
```

Comment: External links might stop working in the future, you should post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here

Comment: Thanks @VincentG, will do!

Comment: since you are only retrieving one value, have you tried to use `dlookup` ? regarding the dao issue. you need to roll back your office updates any version prior to 2005

Comment: Try adding `.Fields`: `localRS.Fields(0).Value`. I know of a bug with the `Decimal` data type and DAO that has been reported in the latest update, but if this is a bug it's new to me.

Comment: Thanks @Krish that did the trick! Reverting back to Version 2004 (Build 12730.20270) made my DAO issue go away. Will have to watch for Office updates until this is fixed...

Comment: is the table name in fact "table"? If yes, you will most likely retrieve table definition stuff with your SQL statement and you should rename the table to something like "yeardata" etc. (but to be honest I did not have the time to test it myself)